# How do I remove the "+" and country code from a phone number?

Tags: java, android, regex

I am using following API to get a phone number; however, some of the device will return the number in following format:

"+" + countrycode + phone number Ex. +12062436969

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String phoneNumber = tm.getLine1Number();
```

I would like to find out a way/algorithm to remove this "+" sign and the country code, so I will get only the last ten digits. Ex.  +12062436969 ->  2062436969

I believe I only need the last ten digits. could anyone please suggest any idea?

Answer (score 19):

You should definitely have a look at this amazing library :

<strike>http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/</strike>
https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber

This will solve your problem and might even help you more since you are doing telephony stuff.