# how to remove text from a string

Tags: android

the code below copies list item to clipboard (contact), it works fine however, i want to remove certain characters from the copied number like country codes (+1, +234, +324), "-", spaces and brackets so how do it do that?

```
public void doCopy(String text) {
    try {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {
            android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            clipboard.setText(text);
        } else {
            android.content.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.content.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            android.content.ClipData clip = android.content.ClipData
                    .newPlainText("WordKeeper", text);
            clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
        }
        this.finish();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Contact copied!", 5000).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error copying contact!", 5000).show();

    }
}
```

here is what i have tried so far but it is not doing anything

```
public void doCopy(String text) {
    try {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {
            android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            clipboard.setText(text);
            text.replace("+1", "");//
        } else {
            android.content.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.content.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            android.content.ClipData clip = android.content.ClipData
                    .newPlainText("WordKeeper", text);
            clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
            text.replace("+1", "");//
        }
        this.finish();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Contact copied!", 5000).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error copying contact!", 5000).show();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: text.replace("+1", ""); // returning the string so store it like that
text = text.replace("+1", "");

Comment: To me this seems like a duplicate. You should checkout regex for this.

Comment: Check [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760800/how-do-i-remove-the-and-country-code-from-a-phone-number), it might answer half your question.

Answer (score 3):

`text.replace("+1", "");` does replace the string but doesn't modify the original string. So you should do this

```
text = text.replace("+1", "");
```

Comment: may be because replace get char not string. so you can use regular expression. and i am bad to make reg exp. sorry

Comment: Answer is correct. Use the second line of code not first. @KhizarHayat I hope you don't mind me editing your answer.

Comment: i replaced "text.replace("+1", "");" with "text = text.replace("+1", "");
" and it still didnt work

Comment: does this line come after     clipboard.setText(text);?

Comment: No, it would come before that.

Comment: it is not working!! can you please post a **snippet** instead of posting a one line answer?

Comment: String text = "+155";
        text = text.replace("+1", "");
it gives me 55

Comment: @Felicia I guess you didn't notice. this is not my answer. And the same code works for me :D

Comment: If you give me sample of texts you get and your desired result. I shall be write an answer for you using regex. that would be better than simple string replacement.

Comment: Its not that I didn't read. there could be various types of scenarios like how country code and phone number is separated.

Comment: @Felicia, I suggest you to watch some other answer... because they might have solution

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the "+" sign using backslashes.

```
text = text.replace("\\+1", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the below expression to remove all unwanted characters from your phone number string

```
        String text = "+1 3545,453455";
    text = text.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");

    // for example the country code is +1
    String country_code = "+1".replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");

    System.out.println(text.substring(country_code.length(), text.length()));
```

Comment: @Rohit5k2, I test it on Eclipse before the post my answer

Comment: My bad. didn't notice "negation". Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that you have 10 static country codes to handle then with context to your code in question, solution can be

```
text = text.toString().replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "").replace("+1", "");
```

This will strip all the the formatting from the number and give you number without any formatting and without country code. Just in case you require to also have the originally copied number then instead of storing value back in `text`, you could use separate variable.

Comment: there are only 10 country codes i want to add so i can handle that without a library

Comment: For me this regex replaces all the spaces and give me number without space and other formatting too `String unformatted_number = number.toString().replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "")` then in unformatted_number you can give `unformatted_number = unformatted_number.replace("+1","")`, the solution given by @Khizar Hayat

Comment: can you check my code in question and edit your answer?

Comment: dude where should i place this line "text = text.toString().replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "").replace("+1", "");"?

Comment: replace this line `text.replace("+1", "");//` in your code with the one i mentioned

Comment: you did that but you did not assign the value after replacing to text variable that is the main problem. you just wrote `text.replace("+1", "");` which should be `text = text.replace("+1", "");` ... you are replacing +1 but will replace in memory but value is not updated in text variable